# Convert HTML Table to JSON with Selectboxes

Tags: jquery, html, json, html-table

I have the following table, which contains selectboxes, and I want to create a JSON string. 
I tried several code snippets but none gave me a correct output.
The output I want to have should be like:

```
id[0]: start time: 12:34;end time: 15:00
id[1]: start time: 18:14;end time: 18:17
```

etc

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script language="Javascript">

function addRowEntry(tableID){
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
        }
      }



</script>

<table id="dynTable" name="dynTable" border=0 width="200px"> 
<thead>
<tr height="50" id="header">

    <td class="datacell"  align="center">Heure Start</td>

    <td class="datacell"  align="center">Min Start</td>
    <td class="datacell"  align="center">Heure End</td>

    <td class="datacell"  align="center">Min End</td>
    <td class="datacell" ><input type="button" value="Ajouter" name="add" id="add" style="width:50px" onclick="addRowEntry('dynTable');"/></td>
</tr>
</thead>    
<tbody>
<tr id="TimeSel">
<td class="datacell" >
    <select id="openH" name="openH">
        <option></option>
        <?php 
            for ($i=0;$i<24;$i++) {
                echo "<option id=$i>";
                echo $i;
                echo "</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</td>

<td class="datacell" >
    <select id="openM" name="openM">
        <option></option>
        <?php 
            for ($i=0;$i<60;$i++) {
                echo "<option id=$i>";
                echo $i;
                echo "</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</td>
<td class="datacell" >
    <select name="closeH" id="closeH">
        <option></option>
        <?php 
            for ($i=0;$i<24;$i++) {
                echo "<option id=$i>";
                echo $i;
                echo "</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</td>

<td class="datacell" >
    <select name="closeM" id="closeM">
        <option></option>
        <?php 
            for ($i=0;$i<60;$i++) {
                echo "<option id=$i>";
                echo $i;
                echo "</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</td>
</tbody>
</tr>

</table>

<input type="button" id="AddDateTime" name="AddDateTime" value="OK" onclick="tableToJson('dynTable');"></input>
```

Edit: I deleted the include file. Was jused for some tests:

Comment: Do you want only select boxes or text too like `Heure Start`?

Comment: You are including jquery but you don't use it.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I want to have a json string like the following : id[0]: start time: 12:34;end time: 15:00
id[1]: start time: 18:14;end time: 18:17

Comment: Do you want it to be JSON, or to be formatted like in your question? What you are describing is not valid JSON.

Comment: the JSON would look like `[{"start time": "12:34", "end time": "15:00"}, {"start time": "18:14", "end time": "18:17"}]`

Comment: well i want it to have an array, no need to have it in json

Comment: Array with two elements like this: `["start time: 12:34;end time: 15:00", "start time: 18:14;end time: 18:17"]`?

Comment: well 2 or more .... but yes

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var val=JSON.stringify(value);
```

in a for loop to capture each element of the array while you are traversing the table. That way you automatically get the required output in JSON format.

EDIT: (using jQuery):

```
var myRows = [];
var $headers = $("th");
var $rows = $("tbody tr").each(function(index) {
  $cells = $(this).find("td");
  myRows[index] = {};
  $cells.each(function(cellIndex) {
    myRows[index][$($headers[cellIndex]).html()] = $(this).html();
  });    
});

var myObj = {};
myObj.myrows = myRows;
alert(JSON.stringify(myObj));​ // to test the output
```

Comment: Thanks George, but there's my problem ... how do I loop thru a table and get the selection options ?

Comment: See my edit above, hope that helps, got the code for looping from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927126/how-to-convert-the-following-table-to-json-with-javascript

Comment: Hi George, thanks for your help, I tried your code, but it gives me the html code for all select boxes and not the selected option

Answer (score 0):

I have used the `.val()` function on the jQuery host object for each `select` element to get the initial value of the selected `option` element. Since you have not specified a `value` attribute, the initial value of each `option` element is set to the contents of the element (from the [HTML 4.01 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.6)).

**JavaScript**

```
function getJSONfromTable(tableID) {

  var res = [];

  // function now expects an id string passed
  $('tbody tr', '#' + tableID).each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    res.push({
      'openH' : parseInt($this.find('#openH').val(), 10),
      'openM' : parseInt($this.find('#openM').val(), 10),
      'closeH': parseInt($this.find('#closeH').val(), 10),
      'closeM': parseInt($this.find('#closeH').val(), 10)
    });
  });

  return JSON.stringify(res);

}

// Example
var json = getJSONfromTable('dynTable');

// Returns (example):
//=> "[{"openH":1,"openM":3,"closeH":6,"closeM":24}, "openH":4,"openM":2,"closeH":12,"closeM":19}]"
```

**A suggestion**

You may or may not be bothered by this but the duplicate `id` attributes you're declaring for each set of `option` elements is invalid according to the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).

> (id) This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

Comment: how should I modify the ID so it will be correct even after inserting new rows ?

Comment: @user2718058 i updated it to add a hash sign to the string you pass into the function. should work now. which ID are you wanting to modify? the `tr` attribute or the `option` attributes?

Answer (score 0):

This is almost an exact duplicate of [Html table to array of json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17988732/912563). In which, the asker has an HTML table of input fields. The HTML table is dynamic, where there can be any number of rows and columns with inputs.

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18133864/912563) wraps the entire `<table>` in a `<form>`, serializes that form, and then loops through the serialization to put it into a more desired format.

Some issues with your code, you are going to have duplicate IDs for your `<option>` tags, which is bad. Also, you are closing your `</tbody>` before you close your `</tr>`, which is also wrong.